# Dynamically creating images with URI encoding Asynchronously with lazy load in a Web Forms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, lazy-loading

I'm dynamically creating many images in a Web Forms application with data URI encoding (no HttpHandler). The images are loaded from a database and I'm filtering with Isotope and lazy loading. I'm using asynchronous tasks in the page load to fetch the data and load into the image controls.
I've created thumbnails and applied image compression as well. Regardless, page load is very slow. I have a white page until all content is loaded.
Am I handling the Async methods correctly? Shouldn't this allow the display of the other content on the page first?

Page Load Method

```
RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(LoadImages));
```

Load Images method:

```
    public Task LoadImages()
    {
        //Get Data from DB
        DataTable dtImages = GetData();
        int id = 0;
        foreach (DataRow row in dtImages.Rows)
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(row["FILE_ID"].ToString());
            var category = row["CATEGORY"].ToString();
            Byte[] bytes = ((Byte[])row["THUMBNAIL_CONTENT"]);
            
            //Method to create the content on the page:
            CreateDiv(id, bytes);
        }
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

The method to create the HTML Generic Controls:

```
    public void CreateDiv(int imageID, byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        image.ID = "Image" + imageID.ToString() + "";
        if (imageID != 0)
        {
        //My animated gif:
            image.ImageUrl = "images/loader.gif"; ;
        }
        image.Attributes.Add("class", "img-fluid lazy");
        //The actual thumbnail:
        image.Attributes.Add("data-src", GetImage(fileBytes));
        image.Visible = true;
        PlaceHoldersDiv.Controls.Add(image);
    }
```

Method to return the image URI:

```
    public string GetImage(object img)
    {
        return "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])img);
    }
```

Lazy loading script:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    var lazyloadImages = document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy");
    var lazyloadThrottleTimeout;

    function lazyload() {
        if (lazyloadThrottleTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(lazyloadThrottleTimeout);
        }

        lazyloadThrottleTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
            var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
            lazyloadImages.forEach(function (img) {
                if (img.offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + scrollTop)) {
                    img.src = img.dataset.src;
                    img.classList.remove('lazy');
                }
            });
            if (lazyloadImages.length == 0) {
                document.removeEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
                window.removeEventListener("resize", lazyload);
                window.removeEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
            }
        }, 20);
    }

    document.addEventListener("scroll", lazyload);
    window.addEventListener("resize", lazyload);
    window.addEventListener("orientationChange", lazyload);
});
```

FYI, I tried using an Http Handler to load the images but performance was much worse!

Comment: Hum, the page has to finish the code behind and THEN sends the whole page down to the client. If that code is not finished, then this will not work. You have to run the code without waits and then let the page get sent back down to the client. But then again, if page is sent then you can't change anything with code behind (even via async since that code behind will be changing the server side page copy - not the one sitting client side. So either you get out quick and let the page go client side. So after page is sent to client, you need to use ajax calls to pull + load the images.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Does this mean I need to scratch the whole CreateDiv method in code behind and generate all of the HTML controls from an Ajax call? Would I have to send the image bytes from the server through an Ajax call?

Comment: Code behind could at least create  "divs" or holding spots (with a id). Page has to render and go down client side (and then you run ajax calls). Some form of grid or even list view with say a image or image button is nice. At least the grid or display would have place holders for the ajax code to fill. Being images from a database then no URL's (and thus no auto multiple threading by the browser). You have to thus pull them down.  I send smallish images from databases all the time into say a listview during code behind (being small - no delay occurs). Thus question how to load image with ajax